# Ruby on Rails - undefined local variable or method - wice grid haml show_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, wice-grid

I am new to ruby on rails.

I am trying to get haml and wice_grid to work together. I am using this example as a model:

http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com/basics3

I get the error 'undefined local variable or method `show_code' for...'

In the file app/views/basics3/index.html.haml which you can see at the link above.

Am I missing a gem? In general, what is the best way to troubleshoot problems like this?

Thanks in advance-

Flex

EDIT: I found the definition for show_code. It's in a helper that I found in the unit tests for wice_grid.

https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid_testbed/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb

That said, I get more errors when I load it into my project. So the question becomes, how does the helper normally get included in my project?

Answer (score 1):

show_code is a custom method created just for the example page you linked to. It just displays the code he has in his controller and his index and grid views. You don't need to call that method in your own application so just remove that line and you should be good.